# iOS UIView Transition subview misplacement for a short while

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I am using `UIView` transition to transit between `ViewControllers`. There is a noticeable *subview* misplacement after the transition is done, which then gets corrected after a short delay.

I have recorded a short video clip to illustrate this problem:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-iP0P7UfFj0dEE3OVN5Q3BTbUU/edit?usp=sharing

Please pay attention to the slider, and also the latent appearance of the titles of buttons

This is a helper method to do the transition:

```
#define DURATION_TRANSITION 0.5

+ (void)toVCWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier transition:(Transition)transition {
    UIViewAnimationOptions option;
    if (transition == TransitionRootToSub) {
        option = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp;
    }
    else if (transition == TransitionSubToRoot) {
        option = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown;
    }
    else if (transition == TransitionPresent) {
        option = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom;
    }
    else if (transition == TransitionDismiss) {
        option = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop;
    }
    else {
        option = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve;
    }
    [UIView transitionWithView:[Helper window] duration:DURATION_TRANSITION options:option animations:^{
        [Helper window].rootViewController = [Helper viewControllerWithStoryboardID:identifier];
    } completion:nil];

}



+ (UIViewController *)viewControllerWithStoryboardID:(NSString *)storyboardID {
    if (IS_IPHONE) {
        return [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];
    }
    else {
        return [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];
    }

}
```

And I simply call to make the transition

```
#define VC_MORE @"MoreViewController" //story board identifier

- (IBAction)setting:(id)sender {
    [Helper toVCWithIdentifier:VC_MORE transition:TransitionRootToSub];
}
```

And in `MoreViewController`, I call this to go back to main

```
#define VC_MAIN @"MainViewController"

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [Helper toVCWithIdentifier:VC_MAIN transition:TransitionSubToRoot];
}
```

Comment: Because you have animation applied to the layer all other setters will be ignored until the animation is completed. So if you have some setters in `viewDidLoad` or so they will be applied =when animation on the layer is completed. This is the reason why you see this misplacements.

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov thanks for the explanation. Any workaround to this problem?